# "www.'' Not working on website hosted in Firebase

Tags: firebase, url, redirect, hosting, firebase-hosting

I hosted a static page using Free Firebase Hosting, but found that if I used `www.` Before the full URL, the browser says "Privacy Error" and this could scare my customers.

✔️ `example.web.app` - Works

❌ `www.example.web.app` - Doesn't work

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7phs.png)

For context, I'm a student and decided to use Firebase because their hosting is free, up to an extent. I read that I could fix this error message by buying a domain but that for me would defeat the purpose of using Firebase in the first place.
For more context, the problem is that the design studio we hired messed up and printed the wrong URL. Now we have a bunch of useless pamphlets that say `www.example.web.app`.

TL;DR. Is there a way to redirect `www.example.web.app` to `example.web.app`?
Preferably explain as if I were 5, Firebase and Hosting in general is too new for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to configure the DNS for your domain in whatever way your DNS provider requires.

Comment: I don't think I have a DNS provider. All I can configure on my end are the options in the Firebase Console and in my website's JSON file.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the domain assigned to you by Firebase (*.web.app), know that you can't change the way that domain works.  It's fully under control by Firebase and maintained automatically for free as a convenience for you.

If you want control over your site's name in the URL, you will need to [connect your own domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain) that you purchase from some DNS provider.